# Graph API - ErrorAuthenticating

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I had working Graph API for months and now have suddenly stopped working.
Endpoint is - Create Call
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls

Error message - 400 - Bad Request

Error : 400 Bad Request
{
"error": {
"code": "AuthenticationError",
"message": "Error authenticating with resource",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-01-23T22:40:42",
"request-id": "641d13fa-c99b-4587-b188-214b7d4da732",
"client-request-id": "641d13fa-c99b-4587-b188-214b7d4da732"
}
}
}

I’ve parsed JWT token, Correct audience is issued for the token.

Token was generated using client_credentials flow - and same can be confirmed in JWT.

Any help ?

Comment: Can you provide a complete request? Include the request body.

Comment: Just sent you details , refer this link for body https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request

Comment: You tried only the VOIP calls when you tried making the Create call, right?

Comment: Also talk to your administrator whether the tenant has the necessary license and its not expired as well. Its worth to give a try as well.

Comment: The issue is fixed. It was due to expired licenses at tenant level.
GA had to enable few licence sku and configure new client secrets to make the API working.